# How to solve the integral equation $f(x)=\frac{\lambda\int_{x}^1 \sqrt{1+(f(t))^2}dt+c_1}{\int_{x}^1 \sqrt{1+(f(t))^2}dt+c_2}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Recently, I have asked a question about variational analysis ([First moments of uniform distribution on a curve from (0,0) to (1,1) in two-space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359130/first-moments-of-uniform-distribution-on-a-curve-from-0-0-to-1-1-in-two-spac)). Such the question can be addressed in some cases by solving the following integral function:

$f(x)=\frac{\lambda\int_{x}^1 \sqrt{1+(f(t))^2}dt+c_1}{\int_{x}^1 \sqrt{1+(f(t))^2}dt+c_2}$,
where $f(x)\in\mathbf{C}^1[0,1]$, and $\lambda$, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constant numbers.

How to solve the above nonlinear equation?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think that something is wrong because $f(0)=(-1)^{-0.5}$ is not allowed.

Comment: Yes. $q>1$ (the integral constant) .

Comment: Let us put $x=0$ in the equation under consideration. This implies $c=0$ and then $f(x)=\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment. The original posted question is indeed wrong, and now I have edited it.

Comment: Both original and edited questions are MSE topics. The integral equation under consideration can be reduced to a certain ODE of the first order by its differentiating and taking into account $$ \int_{x}^1 \sqrt{1+(f(t))^2}dt=-{\frac {f \left( x \right) c_{2}-c_{1}}{f \left( x \right) -\lambda}},\,f(1)= \frac {c_1} {c_2}.$$ Maple 2019.1 solves it in terms of roots of a certain transcendental equation. That huge solution is useless.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any numericial method to solve this equation?

Comment: Precisely you get an ODE with separable variables, whence by integration you get a not too complicated expression for the *inverse* of $f$ in terms of elementary functions (the trascendental equation for $f$) combining logarithms, rational terms, and square roots). An explicit expression for $f$ seems out of reach though

Answer (score 1):

$f(x).\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1+{f(t)}^2} dt =c+\lambda =a$

Say, $f(x)=y$

So, $\frac{d (\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1+{y(t)}^2} dt)}{dx} =\frac{d\frac{a}{y}}{dx}$

From Newton- Leibniz's formula

$\sqrt{1+y^2}=a\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{y})$

Taking $z=(\frac{1}{y})^2$ , we get

$\sqrt{1+z}=a\frac{dz}{dx}$

or, $\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1+z}}= \frac{dx}{a}$

Or, $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\frac{x}{a}+q)^2-1}}$ ,   ($q>1$ for $a>1$, $q<1$ for $a<0$)

Putting the result $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\frac{x}{a}+q)^2-1}}$ we can easily see that the integral equation is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks. I have noticed that $f(x)\cdot\int_0^x\sqrt{1+f^2}dt=c+\lambda$ is used in your answer, which is not implied by the integral equation.